# All my shape fills modified by anchor point tools have broken fill color (Check Image pls)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anchor-point

All the shapes in every .ai file that I have created now appear distorted around the edges where I have  used the anchor point tool . Please check the image around the characters neck and the curves used for the couch. Can anyone please help. This has never happened before.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this was a GPU error. Fixed it using the instructions here

https://helpx.adobe.com/in/illustrator/kb/gpu-performance-errors-troubleshooting-workarounds.html